# ASP.NET Detailed Error Messages Enabled

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7.5

I need one help here. We have our site is running on windows server 2008\IIS7.5. we did PCI scan for our site today and we getting below vulnerability message.

> Vulnerability : - ASP.NET Detailed Error Messages Enabled
>   The web server running on this host is configured to display verbose
>   error messages for ASP.NET applications. This could give an attacker
>   information about the ASP.NET applications on the server, as well
>   as information about the host itself.  However, if you view
>   the source of the page, hidden at the bottom of the document is quite a
>   bit of debugging information that includes the path of the web server.
>   Service: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>
> Remediate Action : - It is recommended that any sort of debugging information be disabled
>   for production systems. Displaying custom error messages prevents
>   the debugging information from being provided to users. In web.config,
>   set the customErrors mode to "On" or "RemoteOnly" (displays
>   debugging information to browsers accessing the site from the local
>   host).

I checked our web.config and we can see below settings there

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/ProcessError.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/PageNotFound.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/ProcessError.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

According to the remediation action, we have set CustomErrors mode to "On" or "RemoteOnly" . As you can see from the above web.config file it is already set to on. Not sure what other changes has to be done.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Looks like a false positive to me... but you can verify that this is indeed working as expected by generating an application error and making sure that you are redirected according to your settings (i.e. to PageNotFound.aspx for 404's and ProcessError.aspx for any other kind of error).

Comment: That's what mine look like more or less, do you have debug = true somewhere further up perhaps?

Comment: @lcarus - I also think that it is a false alarm or what. I verified that our redirects are working when the application errors are coming.

Comment: @syn123 - Debug = false. Confirmed